# MySql database comes back to previus state after system reboot

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a MySql database 
Server version: 5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 (Ubuntu)
and the table City in it.

I am working on Spring-MVC - hibernate, so I am doing changes to the database from @entity annotations.

The first time I created the table I made the column "name" :

```
CREATE TABLE `City` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `stateId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_tr4eopukpxbiked4okmvk3txd` (`stateId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_tr4eopukpxbiked4okmvk3txd` FOREIGN KEY (`stateId`) REFERENCES `State` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

a few days after, I changed the column "name" to "nameEn" and I add the column "nameLc" :

```
CREATE TABLE `City` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nameEn` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nameLc` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `stateId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_tr4eopukpxbiked4okmvk3txd` (`stateId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_tr4eopukpxbiked4okmvk3txd` FOREIGN KEY (`stateId`) REFERENCES `State` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

From that day on, every time I restart my computer, this table (and some others with simmilar changes) returns to the first state :

```
CREATE TABLE `City` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `stateId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_tr4eopukpxbiked4okmvk3txd` (`stateId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_tr4eopukpxbiked4okmvk3txd` FOREIGN KEY (`stateId`) REFERENCES `State` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The bug does not happen when I restart the service, it happens only when I restart the computer (ubuntu)

This is the error.log :

```
160219  8:59:34 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Normal shutdown

160219  8:59:34 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
160219  8:59:34  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
160219  8:59:36  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 2507506155
160219  8:59:36 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

160219  8:59:36 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
160219  8:59:36 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160219  8:59:36 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
160219  8:59:36 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
160219  8:59:36 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
160219  8:59:36 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
160219  8:59:36 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160219  8:59:36 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
160219  8:59:36  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
160219  8:59:37 InnoDB: 5.5.47 started; log sequence number 2507506155
160219  8:59:37 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
160219  8:59:37 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
160219  8:59:37 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
160219  8:59:37 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
160219  8:59:37 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
160219  9:09:39 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Normal shutdown

160219  9:09:39 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
160219  9:09:39  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
160219  9:09:41  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 2509266518
160219  9:09:41 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

160219  9:09:41 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
160219  9:09:41 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160219  9:09:41 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
160219  9:09:41 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
160219  9:09:41 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
160219  9:09:41 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
160219  9:09:41 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160219  9:09:41 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
160219  9:09:41  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
160219  9:09:42 InnoDB: 5.5.47 started; log sequence number 2509266518
160219  9:09:42 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
160219  9:09:42 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
160219  9:09:42 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
160219  9:09:42 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
160219  9:09:42 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
160219  9:13:10 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Normal shutdown

160219  9:13:10 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
160219  9:13:10  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
160219  9:13:11  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 2509266518
160219  9:13:11 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

160219  9:13:48 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
160219  9:13:48 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160219  9:13:48 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
160219  9:13:48 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
160219  9:13:48 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
160219  9:13:48 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
160219  9:13:48 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160219  9:13:48 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
160219  9:13:48  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
160219  9:13:49 InnoDB: 5.5.47 started; log sequence number 2509266518
160219  9:13:49 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
160219  9:13:49 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
160219  9:13:49 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
160219  9:13:49 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
160219  9:13:49 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
```

my.cnf file is :

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
character_set_server           = utf8                                # If you prefer utf8
collation_server               = utf8_general_ci
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer_size     = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover_options  = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#log_slow_queries   = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id      = 1
#log_bin            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
#binlog_do_db       = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db   = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem



[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

can you help me to understand and solve this bug?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL allows you to create a temp table with a existing name. Probably MySQL creates temporary table when you try to create table with the same name as existing. A temporary table is visible in the session only, so after you restart your computer, it is dropped.

If you want to make changes to existing table use:

```
ALTER TABLE
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunatly this is not the case.
For testing your suggestion I dropped the schema and I recreated it empty, without tables in it, and then I let hibernate recreate all the objects. So there was n't any changes in tables but only create. All were fine, except when I reboot the conputer, the schema was in a previus state. For example, as I descriped in the problem, table City has not later created columns : nameEn and nameLc but only name. Somehow database remembers a snapsot, and for some reason returns all the schema to it.

Answer (score 0):

Since I didn't found the reason of the problem, I finally created a copy of the existing db with a different name and the problem disappeared.